# Not able to load data in segmented control tableview from Firestore database

Tags: swift, firebase, uitableview, google-cloud-firestore, uisegmentedcontrol

I am trying to populate table view w.r.t the segmented control by getting data from Firestore database, but due to some reason I am not being able to do so, I am trying an example available online which has preset data, but here I am retrieving data from the Firestore database.

It is not giving any runtime error as well, simply not loading the data. Below is the screenshot of the view controller of the code. Kindly assist

[image]

```
class FirstSegementViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var segmentControl:UISegmentedControl!

    @IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!

    var s1Post:[s1] = []
    var s2Post:[s2] = []


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        retrieveAllPosts()
    }


    func retrieveAllPosts(){
        let postsRef = Firestore.firestore().collection("posts").limit(to: 50)

        postsRef.getDocuments { (snapshot, error) in

            if let error = error {

                print(error.localizedDescription)

            } else {

                if let snapshot = snapshot {

                    for document in snapshot.documents {


                        let data = document.data()
                        //self.postKey = document.documentID
                        let username = data["post_author_username"] as? String ?? ""
                        let postTitle = data["postTitle"] as? String ?? ""
                        let postcategory = data["postcategory"] as? String ?? ""
                        let postContent = data["postContent"] as? String ?? ""
                        let postAuthorProfilePicUrl = data["post_user_profile_pic_url"] as? String ?? ""
                        let postAuthorSpinnerC = data["post_author_spinnerC"] as? String


                        let newSourse = s1(_documentId: document.documentID, _username: username, _postTitle: postTitle, _postcategory: postcategory, _postContent: postContent, _postuserprofileImagUrl: postAuthorProfilePicUrl, _postAuthorSpinncerC: postAuthorSpinnerC)

                        self.s1Post.append(newSourse)
                        // print(self.postKey)
                    }
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                }
            }
        }
    }




    @IBAction func indexChanged(_ sender: UISegmentedControl) {
          switch segmentControl.selectedSegmentIndex
         {
         case 0:
            retrieveAllPosts()
         // label1.text = "First Segment Selected"
         case 1:

            retrieveAllPosts()
         // label1.text = "Second Segment Selected"
         default:
         break
         }

        //self.tableView.reloadData()
    }

    /*
     // MARK: - Navigation

     // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
     override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
     // Get the new view controller using segue.destination.
     // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
     }
     */



    /*
    // MARK: - Navigation

    // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        // Get the new view controller using segue.destination.
        // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    }
    */

}


extension FirstSegementViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource{

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        var value = 0
        switch segmentControl.selectedSegmentIndex{
        case 0:
            value = s1Post.count
            break
        case 1:
            value = s2Post.count
            break
        default:
            break
        }
        return value
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MyCell", for: indexPath) as! MyWsPostCell
        switch segmentControl.selectedSegmentIndex{
        case 0:
            cell.s11 = s1Post[indexPath.row]
            break
        case 1:
            cell.s21 = s2Post[indexPath.row]
            break

        default:
            break
        }
        return cell
    }


}
```

Comment: Have you checked adding dummy data from a demo array of yours? Does it work fine?
Also have you connected `tableView.delegate = self` and `tableView.dataSource = self`

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be setting value for self.s1Post only.

Comment: yes, just to check it, shall I set values for both? I was trying to retrieve list for atleast one